# Azure App Service - Free Tier - Cpu Time (Short)

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm working with two different Azure accounts - my own and the one owned by my employer.

I've set up functionally identical resource groups under both accounts, using the free tier App Service and App Service Plan.

I've deployed the same C# .NET Webforms application to both of them, using slightly different deployment processes.

When I right-click publish to my personal account the process is smooth. I can typically use the application within 10-15 minutes.

For the other account, I created a DevOps project and pipeline connected to a GitHub repo. (same code that I'm using above) When I commit changes to the watched branch it takes quite a while for the application to be reachable and usable. The quotas for this App Service indicate that I frequently exceed the Cpu Time (Short) allowed for the Free tier. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I figure something associated with the pipeline is responsible for the increased Cpu usage.

Which leads to my question - does stepping up to the Shared Tier increases the Cpu Time (Short) quota? All have been able to determine is that the Free tier allows for 60 minutes of Cpu Time per day and the Shared tier allows for 240. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5 minute CPU quota aka CPU Short Quota is the same for Free and Shared. You can consume up to three minutes per five minute time period reset every five minutes.

To increase the quota, you will need to select Basic or above.

[Azure App Service Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)

[Understanding Azure App Service Quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor)